# Keep user logged in inside the Iframe

Tags: php, html, security, iframe

I am using webmail in an iframe and I want that whenever I refresh my page user should not be logged out.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow - typically you will want to attempt to write some code after researching it online or doing tutorials.  Once you have done this post you code / errors here for support.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: _“It is really urgent”_ - no, it is not. Nothing you ask here ever is. This is a community of volunteers answering other people’s questions, so let them do that in their own time at least. If you need “urgent” support, then you can go and **pay** for it somewhere.

Comment: I just need an urgent suggestion can we do this.?
Also if I got a question which doesn't require any code then what should I write?

Comment: <iframe src="https://webmail.mydomain.com/" style="width: 100%;height: 800px;border: none;"></iframe>

This is what I am using